# With cpan and cpanm, why are some modules recognized as already up-to-date, but others are re-installed every time despite being up-to-date?

Tags: perl, cpan

UPDATE:

One difference I found was that Data::Show uses Module::Build, while Data::Dumper uses a Build file (using vimdiff):

[image: vimdiff shows that Data::Dumper uses a Makefile, while Data::Show uses a Build file.]

---

I've noticed that with cpan and cpanm, some modules are not reinstalled when there isn't a newer version, but others are reinstalled every time. I don't have anything in my `PERL5LIB` variable and my `@INC` includes all the right paths. I am using perlbrew, but I think that I had similar problems using a custom-built perl:

```
  %ENV:
    PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION="0.73"
    PERLBREW_HOME="/home/username/.perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_MANPATH="/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/man"
    PERLBREW_PATH="/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/user/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/bin"
    PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.20.1"
    PERLBREW_ROOT="/home/username/perl5/perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_VERSION="0.73"
    PERLDEV="/share/data/username/Perl5"
  @INC:
    /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/x86_64-linux
    /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1
    /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/5.20.1/x86_64-linux
    /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/5.20.1
```

`Data::Dumper` doesn't get reinstalled when there isn't a newer version:

```
cpanm Data::Dumper
Data::Dumper is up to date. (2.154)
```

However, `Data::Show` gets reinstalled every time:

```
$ cpanm Data::Show
--> Working on Data::Show
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DC/DCONWAY/Data-Show-0.002002.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Data-Show-0.002002 ... OK
Building and testing Data-Show-0.002002 ... OK
Successfully installed Data-Show-0.002002
1 distribution installed

$ cpanm Data::Show
--> Working on Data::Show
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DC/DCONWAY/Data-Show-0.002002.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Data-Show-0.002002 ... OK
Building and testing Data-Show-0.002002 ... OK
Successfully installed Data-Show-0.002002
1 distribution installed
```

Results of cpanm -v Data::Show

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7027 on perl 5.020001 built for x86_64-linux
Work directory is /home/username/.cpanm/work/1424150236.20375
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 6.13
You have /bin/tar: tar (GNU tar) 1.23
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching Data::Show on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on Data::Show
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/D/DC/DCONWAY/Data-Show-0.002002.tar.gz ... OK
Unpacking Data-Show-0.002002.tar.gz
Data-Show-0.002002/
Data-Show-0.002002/Build.PL
Data-Show-0.002002/Changes
Data-Show-0.002002/lib/
Data-Show-0.002002/Makefile.PL
Data-Show-0.002002/MANIFEST
Data-Show-0.002002/META.yml
Data-Show-0.002002/README
Data-Show-0.002002/t/
Data-Show-0.002002/t/00.load.t
Data-Show-0.002002/t/pod.t
Data-Show-0.002002/t/show.t
Data-Show-0.002002/lib/Data/
Data-Show-0.002002/lib/Data/Show.pm
Entering Data-Show-0.002002
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have ExtUtils::MakeMaker 0 ... Yes (6.98)
Running Build.PL
Configuring Data-Show-0.002002 ... Module::Build will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release. Please install it from CPAN. It is being used at Build.PL, line 3.
Created MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Creating new 'Build' script for 'Data-Show' version '0.002002'
OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.json ...
Checking if you have version 0 ... Yes (0.9909)
Checking if you have Data::Dump 1.17 ... Yes (1.22)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (1.001014)
Building and testing Data-Show-0.002002 ... Module::Build will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release. Please install it from CPAN. It is being used at ./Build, line 40.
Building Data-Show
Module::Build will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release. Please install it from CPAN. It is being used at ./Build, line 40.
t/00.load.t .. 1/1 # Testing Data::Show 0.002002
t/00.load.t .. ok
t/pod.t ...... skipped: Test::Pod 1.14 required for testing POD
t/show.t ..... Smartmatch is experimental at t/show.t line 28.
t/show.t ..... ok
All tests successful.
Files=3, Tests=64,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.06 usr  0.02 sys +  0.12 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.23 CPU)
Result: PASS
Module::Build will be removed from the Perl core distribution in the next major release. Please install it from CPAN. It is being used at ./Build, line 40.
Building Data-Show
OK
Successfully installed Data-Show-0.002002
Installing /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/x86_64-linux/.meta/Data-Show-0.002002/install.json
1 distribution installed
```

Very interestingly, they are not both installing to a place that perldoc can see:

```
$ perldoc -l Data::Dump
/home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Data/Dump.pm
$ perldoc -l Data::Show
No documentation found for "Data::Show".
```

Comment: Using `cpanm -v ...` may provide some clues

Comment: Please show the full output of the installation (as `cpan Data::Show` would do). Presumably nothing was changed was for some reason

Comment: Also, `perl -E'use Data::Show; say "<$Data::Show::VERSION>"'`?

Comment: What I'd hoped for was the result of `cpanm -v Data::Show`. And since you're using `perlbrew` can you confirm that you are using `cpanm` from within _that_ install (e.g. `which cpanm`). If not, `cpan -i App::cpanminus`

Comment: Or you know, just use `cpan`. Hard to forget to install that one since it comes with Perl, and it doesn't hide relevant diagnostics.

Comment: @BenGrimm Thanks so much for your great troubleshooting ideas!

Comment: @ikegami Thanks so much for your great troubleshooting ideas!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like my problem was that Build.PL files are not working for some reason. When I saw that `Data::Show` comes with both a `Build.PL` file and a `Makefile.PL`, I tried installing it manually using the Makefile and then it installed:

```
perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Data::Show
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
$ make
cp lib/Data/Show.pm blib/lib/Data/Show.pm
Manifying blib/man3/Data::Show.3
$ make install
Installing /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/site_perl/5.20.1/Data/Show.pm
Installing /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/man/man3/Data::Show.3
Appending installation info to /home/username/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.20.1/lib/5.20.1/x86_64-linux/perllocal.pod
$ cpanm Data::Show
Data::Show is up to date. (0.002002)
```

Comment: Sounds like something is telling `cpanm` or Module::Build to install into the wrong location. Looks like this `cpanm` can't be configured, so maybe one of Module::Build's env var: `PERL_MB_OPT` and `MODULEBUILDRC`.

Comment: @ikegami That's it. Could you please post that as an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!